# EmptyClassBlock lint complaint on Json TypeToken

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, detekt

I have a piece of kotlin code as below,

```
gson.fromJson<Map<String, JsonElement>>(data, 
   object : TypeToken<Map<String, JsonElement>>() {}.type)
```

`Detekt` doesn't like it and complaint `EmptyClassBlock - [<UnknownName>]`

Is there any way I could resolve that?

Comment: Either suppress your static anlysis tool or use TypeToken.getParameterized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exact case was removed from the `EmptyClassBlock` rule in this PR: https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt/pull/665

It should be available in the latest detekt release (RC6-2) already. After updating detekt you shouldn't need to manually `@Suppress` these cases (objects of abstract classes) anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It can be suppressed by annotating the code with `@Suppress("EmptyClassBlock")`
(Described [here](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt/blob/master/README.md#suppress))

Here’s the list of [rule ids](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt/blob/master/detekt-cli/src/main/resources/default-detekt-config.yml), one of which has to be passed an an argument to the annotation (`EmptyClassBlock` in your case).

Comment: Thanks. I know the suppression. I'm just checking if there's a way to do it without need to suppress it.

Comment: It’s such a rare case, suppression is fine imho